# How to display NSTimeInterval binding as NSDate in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: interface-builder, double, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I handle a lot of time stamps that I store as NSTimeInterval.

```
NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear: ....
NSDate* date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Interface Builder has a table view binding to the variable of the time stamp.
How can I format the (double value of) NSTimeInterval into a human readable date format?
The Interface Builder *Table Column Bindings palette* has a input field *Value Transformer* - can I do something here?

Comment: Or would you put the conversion into the source code so IB can show an NSDate instead of a double value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to drag and drop NSDateFormatter from the Library panel to the table view cell.

Comment: You're the only person on the Internets that answered this question.